# The usage of do not (don't) and does not (doesn't)

Tags: grammar

This sentence is bugging me:

> Just because you have an opinion, it *doesn't* mean you are right.

Why is **doesn't** used instead of **don't**? Shouldn't it be:

> Just because you have an opinion, it *don't* mean you are right?

Comment: The conjugation is: I do – you do – he/she/it does – we do – you do – they do. So "**it does** not mean..."

Answer (score 1):

Except for modals and subjunctives, the third-person singular present tense form of a verb ends with **s**.

There are a small number of irregular third-person singular forms (such as *is*, *has* and, most relevantly, *does* /dʌz/).

"It" is a third-person singular pronoun.

In the expression "it does", or "it does not", or "it doesn't", the verb needs to be "does" in order to agree with "it".

"It don't" is ungrammatical in standard English.